# How to scale a Java back-end with websockets and event distribution using Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, websocket

I have an application with a Java back-end, a database, and a web front-end. Currently, when a user logs in, the front-end opens a websocket connection to the server to send requests and receive responses. Additionally, the websocket is utilized to send real-time events from the server to the user, eliminating the need for continuous polling.

My goal is to migrate the existing back-end to a horizontally scalable cluster. Currently, the back-end is mostly stateless, with no in-memory caches or sessions. All relevant data is persisted in the database. However, there is an `EventDispatcher` component responsible for handling events. This `EventDispatcher` allows subscriptions on a per user basis. So the websocket endpoint on the server registers for its user on the `EventDispatcher`. When the server produces an event it is sent to the `EventDispatcher` which distributes it to the current listeners. There's no storage of events, if the websocket for a user is not connected, the event is lost. That's because the full state is actually on the database. Events are only there so the front-end doesn't need to poll for changes.

To facilitate scaling, I have chosen Kafka as the message broker for event distribution. My approach involves creating a topic per user, aligning with the current listener-based design. Each server in the cluster will have its own `EventDispatcher`, consisting of a Kafka producer to send events to the broker, and a consumer to retrieve events from the broker and deliver them to the appropriate listeners (websockets).

Unfortunately, the current implementation is not functioning as expected. I suspect that either my design is flawed, or Kafka may not be the ideal tool for this particular use case. Specifically, I am encountering issues when running automated tests that open and close several websockets. When running the application manually it seems to be working fine with a few concurrent users.

I am seeking advice on the best practices for designing an event distribution system that can support horizontal scaling of the server. Additionally, I am open to suggestions on alternative tools or technologies that might better suit this requirement.

Specifically, I would like to know:

- What design considerations should I take into account when scaling
  the `EventDispatcher` to a horizontally scalable cluster?
- Is Kafka the
  appropriate choice for event distribution in this scenario, or are
  there alternative tools better suited for my needs?
- How can I ensure
  that reconnected websockets receive only the most recent events and
  not outdated ones?

Any guidance, code examples, or recommended resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: As Kafka is more designed to ensure that the listeners receive all events, it might not be ideal for your point 3 ("receive only the most recent events"). You would have to create a timestamp or counter and find out which messages from a topic you would have to skip.

Comment: While I've seen websockets done on Kafka from vendors like Ably, it's not very straightforward (as told to me by one of the core engineers)... Apache Pulsar instead offers both Kafka client compatibility and websockets, and may fit your needs better than Kafka itself. In any case, asking for software recommendations is off topic for Stackoverflow

Comment: @cyberbrain `auto.offset.reset=latest` kafka consumer config ensures that any consumer will only read records produced after the subscription (i.e latest events) and ignores any existing data